# Bug when clicking through closing options

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to Close Votes review page.
2. Click "Close" -> "off-topic because..."
3. Choose "Other", change your mind, choose something else: now "Vote To Close" button is inactive until you enter something in "Comment" field, even if you choose different option. Becomes active if you change something in "Comment". The button should be inactive only for "Other" choice when comment is default.

EDIT: If I do it from question page, it is deactivated only on first click after "Other". On Close Votes review it doesn't come back until I type something in the Comment.

I'm on Linux Mint 12 with Chrome 28.0.1500.71.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Hmmm.. Well, I can see it, although I've reloaded the browser. It doesn't seem like a temporary glitch.

Comment: I see it kind of blinks (goes to active and then back to inactive).

Comment: Repro on Chrome mobile iOS 6.1.3

Comment: Reproduced just now on this very question, Win7 Chrome 29.0.1547.66

Comment: @Doorknob it seems to be inconsistent.  I just tried it this morning you reported reproducing it on the same OS/Browser and I did manage to reproduce it once from the question page.  But when I tried it a 2nd time, the button was re-enabled immediately after selecting another option.  But still can't repro from the close queue.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Win7 Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m. When I have access to my Linux VMs will try again.

Comment: Just tried it on my home computer Windows XP with Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m. Same thing.

Comment: Have you cleared you cache? Forced a JavaScript fetch (Ctrl + F5 on Windows)? Is it still happening?

Comment: @Oded Yep, no change.

Comment: Repro on Win7 Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m via the review queue. Navigating back to the initial choice screen, closing and reopening the dialog, or typing enough characters in the comment box enables the button. When changing among the options, the button becomes enabled momentarily, then immediately disabled. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OQODA.jpg).