# Bug: Closing Questions with Comment

Tags: bug, comments, stack-exchange, vote-to-close

## Replicate

1. Go to any question
2. Click "close" to vote to close the question.
3. Select "Off-topic".
4. Click "Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)".
5. Click any other close reason.

## Expected Results

The **Vote to Close** button should be enabled.

## Actual Results

The **Vote to Close** button is disabled.

## Work Around

Close the dialog and don't make a mistake the next time.

Comment: Tested on this question. Edited. Also, this is not restricted to reviews.

Comment: I remember this, this is a duplicate. Finding...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197345/bug-when-clicking-through-closing-options?rq=1 There it is. Duplicate.

Comment: Yep, that was it.